# StreamWriter not writing last value

Tags: c#, streamwriter, sqldatareader

I have some code which executes a SQL Stored Procedure and then writes the result to a CSV file, however the last value is not being written to the file.

Code:

```
conn = new SqlConnection(_sConnectionString);
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_PS_Test", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExportDate", DateTime.Now));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SiteId", _iSiteId));

using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    using(StreamWriter salesWriter = new StreamWriter(_sSalesFileName))
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
            salesWriter.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}",rdr["TransactionDate"],rdr["ProductCode"] , rdr["Qty"] ,rdr["Price"] , rdr["NominalCode"]);
        }
```

The column "NominalCode" is not being written to the file, any suggestions?

I have tried the same code but with a different stored procedure and again the last column is missing.

Data returned from stored procedure:

```
TransactionDate ProductCode Qty Price   NominalCode
2015-07-30 00:00:00 SERVICE 1   45.00   4000001
2015-07-30 00:00:00 SERVICE 1   15.00   4000001
```

Also, stupid moment, how can i format the "Price" column to be to currency/money format?

Thank You

Comment: `how can i format the "Price" column to be to currency/money format?` try `{3:C}`

Comment: Are you sure that your stored procedure is returning a column exactly named `NominalCode`? Can you paste a sample of what the stored procedure returns?

Comment: The problem is not the StreamWriter if you mean that it prints multiple lines, but each line misses the last column. It's your data. Go debugging, introduce a variable `string toWrite = string.Format("the format string")`.

Comment: What do you see when you attach a debugger and look at the value of `rdr["NominalCode"]`? Because that's problably what's wrong. It's highly unlikely that the `StreamWriter` ignores that last value because all that method receives is a single string.

Comment: @AndreuRodrígueziDonaire The documentation for String.Format (which the various WriteLine methods use) says `Indexes start at 0`

Comment: @crush When debugging the value of rdr["NominalCode"] is showing as blank, yet if i call the stored procedure manually via SQL the column is populated.

Comment: Can we see the result from your SQL stored procedure? (1 row is enough + the headers returned by SQL. You could copy this out of SSMS)

Comment: I have added a sample data set returned to the original question, hope it helps

Comment: In debugger, what does it say for  `rdr.FieldCount`? Can you find a property for the key names? Everything you've posted should work fine as far as I know. Only thing I can think of is that the column returned from SQL stored procedure isn't actually `NominalCode`, but the result you posted says it is.

Comment: rdr.FieldCount has a value of 5, which is correct.  I don't have a property for key names.  I will go and change the name of the column to a different name and see what i get

Comment: Even changing the column name to "Nom" from "NominalCode" produces a blank value

Comment: The column name has to exactly match what comes back from SQL. Can you do a `Console.WriteLine(rdr.getName(4))` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname(v=vs.110).aspx)) or whatever method you are using to log output. That will tell you the name of the last column

Comment: Also, you could just do `rdr[4]` if you don't care about using the column name to get the value. I like using column names because it makes the code more readable, and also helps if you add new columns to the stored procedure result, or reorder them.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out (as expected I admit) that there was a different underlying issue in the code, where a parameter for the stored procedure was set.  This in turn was not joining correctly to retrieve the require value.

Thank you for the help and advice.